# How to check if there is no server response in Objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, json, server, nsurlconnection

I am trying to hit a web service . All works good. But if the server is not working then my app crashes .
How to handle NO SERVER RESPONSE .
Please help

Here is my code for hitting web service.

```
NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[get setObject:@"0" forKey:@"unit"];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"req=%@",jsonInputString];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",getCommunity]];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (responseData != nil) {
    NSDictionary *jsonRecieveDict = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"jsonArray  =======%@",jsonRecieveDict);
 }
if (error)
{
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Servor not responding" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

** ERROR IS BECAUSE OF INVALID STATUS CODE FROM SERVER **

Comment: Your no server response would be caught in the `error` if server is not responding. About the above code, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @SahebRoy - It works when there is no internet , But if server is down, app crashes. Problem is with **status code** from the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (error != nil) {
    // Something went wrong...
    NSLog(@"Servor not responding %@",error.description);
    return;
}
if ([response statusCode] >= 300) {
    NSLog(@"Servor not responding, status code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
    return;
}
```

First condition should be error checking,Second if response comes check the status code then only perform the remaining operation

Also change `NSURLResponse *response;` to  `NSHTTPURLResponse *response`

**OR diff Implementation**

```
NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[get setObject:@"0" forKey:@"unit"]; 

if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:get]){


//convert object to data
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(response){
        NSString *resp = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Echo %@",resp);


    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"Timeout");

    }



}];
[task resume];


}
```

Comment: response status code is giving  me No visible interface forNSURLRESPONSE declares the selector statusCode

Comment: It takes 20 seconds to load and then shows "Server not responding ". As I have given 20 secs for connection timeOut.

Comment: How to deal with this

Comment: u can't handle the timeout,If timeout occurs show alert Server is taking too much time to respond

Comment: I mean to say that if the server has no response then it shows SOME ERROR immediately . Is this possible>?